# Test with jest in angular

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

I'm using angular material as a designer lib to develop screens, and I'm trying to test one of the methods that MatPaginator has, however, I always get an error.

I'll put it in a summarized way below, the ways I tried and didn't work.

**First try**

```
1 -  let paginator: MatPaginator;

2 -  providers: [
        { provide: MatPaginator, useValue: paginator },
      ],

3 -  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContratoListaComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    paginator = TestBed.inject(MatPaginator);
  });

4 -  it('xxxx', () => {

    const elementos: IContratoSap = {
      lista: [{
        cod: '78548',
        name: 'avenida leste',
        local: 'ap',
        idLocal: 10,
        status: false
      }
      ],
      totalElemento: 2
    } as any;

    const spy = jest.spyOn(fakeServiceMock, 'listarContratos').mockReturnValue(of(elementos));
    const search = 'sim';
    const limite = 10;
    const pagina = 1;
    component.loadData(search, limite, pagina);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('true', limite, pagina);
    expect(component.dataSource.data).toEqual(elementos.lista);
    expect(component.paginator.pageIndex).toBe(component.currentPage); //ERROR
    expect(component.paginator.length).toBe(elementos.totalElemento); //ERROR
  });
```

**second attempt**

```
1 -  let paginator: MatPaginator;

2 -  providers: [
        { provide: MatPaginator, useValue: paginator },
      ],

3 -  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContratoListaComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    paginator = TestBed.inject(MatPaginator);
  });

4 -  it('xxxx', () => {

    const elementos: IContratoSap = {
      lista: [{
        cod: '78548',
        name: 'avenida leste',
        local: 'ap',
        idLocal: 10,
        status: false
      }
      ],
      totalElemento: 2
    } as any;

    const spy = jest.spyOn(fakeServiceMock, 'listarContratos').mockReturnValue(of(elementos));
    const search = 'sim';
    const limite = 10;
    const pagina = 1;
    component.loadData(search, limite, pagina);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('true', limite, pagina);
    expect(component.dataSource.data).toEqual(elementos.lista);
    expect(paginator.pageIndex).toBe(component.currentPage);  //ERROR
    expect(paginator.length).toBe(elementos.totalElementos);  //ERROR
  });
```

And inside the beforeEach(() => , I tried to do it in these ways below:

1 - paginator: TestBed.inject(MatPaginator);

2 - paginator: component.paginator

And all the tests I did with and without the provider.

And the error always occurs in the lines that I expect the pageIndex and length, both signaled with (//ERROR) here in the code.

Comment: I managed to solve it by inserting: { provide: ChangeDetectorRef, useValue: { detectChanges: () => { } } }